# browsing through big amount of images with slider approach

Tags: java, python, image

I have 1000 images, each of them signifies a state at the time step. I would like to create an application that allows us to use a slider move through time steps, eventually being able also to see some information about what is going on in the image (like region size ect). I created the algorithm which creates generates and analyzes images in Python and I guess I will try to create UI in Java. Any recommendations on how to approach it? ( I am not very proficient in Java but I understand the basics). I attached the general view of what I want it to be below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try Tkinter, it is a very easy to use UI creator in python.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html

Comment: hmm nice I did not know about this library, it may work.